# Error during Mono manual installation in CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, rpm, mono

I'm trying to do a Mono install package per package, because the CentOS server doesn't have internet access. However, when I try to install the mono core package using the command:

```
rpm -i mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64.rpm
```

The system displays the following error message:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    mono(System.ComponentModel.Composition) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64
    mono(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64
    mono(System.Data) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64
    mono(System.IdentityModel) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64
    mono(System.Runtime.Serialization) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64
    mono(System.ServiceModel) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64
    mono(System.ServiceProcess) = 4.0.0.0 is needed by mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64
```

How do I solve these dependencies?

UPDATE

I'm trying to use this command:

```
yum localinstall mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Result:

```
Examining mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64.rpm: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64
Marking mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
   Running transaction check
   Package mono-core.x86_64 0:4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1 will be installed
   Processing Dependency: mono(System.ComponentModel.Composition) = 4.0.0.0 for package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64                                                                                                                        
   Processing Dependency: mono(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) = 4.0.0.0 for package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       
   Processing Dependency: mono(System.Data) = 4.0.0.0 for package: mono-core-4.                                                                                                                                                           
   Processing Dependency: mono(System.IdentityModel) = 4.0.0.0 for package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64  
   Processing Dependency: mono(System.Runtime.Serialization) = 4.0.0.0 for package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             
   Processing Dependency: mono(System.ServiceModel) = 4.0.0.0 for package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            
   Processing Dependency: mono(System.ServiceProcess) = 4.0.0.0 for package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             
  Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (/mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64) Requires: mono(System.Data) = 4.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                            
Error: Package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (/mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64) Requires: mono(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) = 4.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                             
Error: Package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (/mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64) Requires: mono(System.IdentityModel) = 4.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                             
Error: Package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (/mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64) Requires: mono(System.ServiceModel) = 4.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                             
Error: Package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (/mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64) Requires: mono(System.ComponentModel.Composition) = 4.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                             
Error: Package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (/mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64) Requires: mono(System.Runtime.Serialization) = 4.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                             
Error: Package: mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (/mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64) Requires: mono(System.ServiceProcess) = 4.0.0.0

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `yum localinstall mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64.rpm` and ideally `yum` will find and fetch the dependencies for you.

Comment: See my edition. unfortunately, It wasn't Work

Answer (score 1):

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
you can force to install the package but may have Dependencies issues later.

Comment: Ok, but how Do I install these dependencies?

Comment: What's your OS version?

Comment: 7.3 is the OS Version

Comment: You need RPM, try this one for CentOS 7, Fedora 19 (and later), and derivatives
Add the Mono Project GPG signing key and the package repository in a root shell with:

yum install yum-utils
rpm --import "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF"
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos/

Comment: The Server doesn't have access the internet. And I already downloaded the packages in the repository on my machine and uploaded it to the server

Comment: Use `rpm -qp --requires mono-core-4.8.1.0-0.xamarin.1.x86_64.rpm` to see the dependencies, and install them by hand.

Comment: Best way to get internet access, or you will have a whole to install the dependencies.

Comment: A question: In which rpm package is the mono (System.ComponentModel.Composition)?